# Is it ok to logout after calling docker stack deploy?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, cicd

If I immediately terminate the process that called `docker stack deploy` will the docker swarm continue?

My use case is this:

1. In my CI job I ssh into my swarm cluster node.
2. I copy the new stack.yml file and issue
3. `docker stack deploy -c stack.yml stack`
4. Since this immediately returns, my CI job disconnects from ssh.

My question is whether this can lead to some unforeseen side-effects? Is my deploy being terminated midway? Or will docker swarm be smart enough to keep going on its own.

Thanks

Comment: You could test it: run the cmd through a ssh session and ctrl-D once you issue it

Comment: I'm getting weird behaviour, regardless of what I do. Some of my services (out of 3 replicas) get updated, while others don't...

Comment: Sounds like it's not safe. Try adding a custom CI step consisting in checking the stack deployment, based on `docker stack stack services` executions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* safe. As soon as docker returns it is safe to logout/leave the shell.

The issue was that Docker 18.06.0-ce **broke** `docker stack deploy`. Reverting to 18.03.1 (specifically `18.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu`) made it work.